# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic> with UTF code U0027 under c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a problem with    `Json "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>"`

I have a `JsonConvert.SerializeObject();`

```
JSonRequest={\r\n                \"fullName\": \"Dr. AS\\\\u0027s  \"\r\n         }
```

And want result:

```
"fullName": "Dr. AS\u0027s  "
```

Using below code but it shows

```
"fullName": "Dr. AS's  "
```

So could you help me how this cab be handled?

I am using below code to Deserialize Object.

```
object JSonRequest2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSonRequest1);
```

Comment: That's a unicode escape character. Do you want it to actually output `Dr.As\u0027s`?

Answer (score 0):

seems this one not a problem. I can repro very well in this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/E3o8AU